# Problem with Python when setting up LDAP for MacOS

Tags: python, macos, ldap

I am trying to set up Google secure LDAP on my Macbook Pro running Monterey 12.3 following [these instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736?#ldap-search&zippy=%2Cmacos) from Google. However I am getting the below error

> File "/users/user/documents/ldap_pythong_config.py", line 2, in
>
> from OpenDirectory import ODNode, ODSession, kODNodeTypeConfigure   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenDirectory/**init**.py",
> line 12, in 
> objc.pathForFramework("/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework"),
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/objc/_dyld.py",
> line 122, in pathForFramework
> fpath, name, version = infoForFramework(dyld_find(path))   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/objc/_dyld.py",
> line 117, in dyld_find
> return dyld_framework(filename, framework_name, version)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/objc/_dyld.py",
> line 88, in dyld_framework
> raise ImportError("Framework %s could not be found" % (framework_name,)) ImportError: Framework OpenDirectory could not be
> found

I've had a troubleshooting session with Google and they recommended I get support from the community.

A few details to note:

- /usr/bin/python does not exist
- /usr/bin/python3 **does** exist
- Python 2.7 is installed
- Python 3 was installed previously and uninstalled. But /usr/bin/python3 still exists

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
You are missing `pyobjc-framework-opendirectory`.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pyobjc-framework-opendirectory
```

After that, you can do `python3 /path/to/the/ldap/script.py`